# CSS File in wwwroot is not refreshing when i change the code ( ASP.NET MVC 6.0)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, upload, wwwroot

My css file :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3KxI.png)

And this file when build : ( not change )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duAEP.png)

Sometime I try "clean-solution" and "build-solution" then it's working, but now isn't working.
Thank.

Comment: Since css files are considered static files ,maybe they are stuck in browser cache,You can test it by pressing CTRL + R or CTRL+SHIFT+R in the browser (if this helps then "Disable Cache" option in browsers might also be useful in future)

Comment: Force clear cache in your browser with `CTRL` + `F5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the CSS file is cached. You can try open the Chrome Dev Tools -> Network tab -> tick the Disable cache checkbox and then F5 to refresh the page. Or just Ctrl+F5 to refresh with no cache.